# Laravel 5.3 Simple Ajax call causes 500 error

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I have a straightforward datatable and also a div which is linked to a sliderreveal.js (a jquery item) which slide in a panel with other information.

In the datatable I have the following line:

```
<td align="center"><input type="image" src="{{ asset('siteicons/prodec/Info_Box_Blue.png')}}" id="trigger" onclick="ShowSlider( {{ $item->Reference }} )" /></td>
```

This fires off a simple javascript method:

```
 function ShowSlider(id)
      {
        $('#slider').load('../ajax/customers.php?id=' + id + "&_token={{  csrf_token() }}" );
        var slider = $('#slider');
        slider.slideReveal("show");
      }
```

The ajax page simply shows some information.

All this works perfectly on localhost but online I get a 500 error.

I searched around the internet and added the csrf token as suggested but it has not made any difference.

Comment: Check your `laravel.log` file for possible errors.

Comment: 500 is a server side error provide us with your laravel controller for customers

Comment: customers has no controller - I just use PDO to get the information on the id. It is independent of Laravel.

Comment: @Jim acces the url directly in the page and see what errors you have

Answer (score 0):

probably it's a error with your url.

If in localhost you access to a subfolder (ie localhost/**folder**/blabla) then you use the **../** to go back of one step.

If in production you don't access with the same path (ie yoursite.com/blabla) (**note** the missing **folder**) you don't find the wanted route.

I suggest you to use a virtualhost in your development environemtn, such as test.local. so you can change your function with:

```
function ShowSlider(id)
  {
    $('#slider').load('/ajax/customers.php?id=' + id + "&_token={{  csrf_token() }}" );
    var slider = $('#slider');
    slider.slideReveal("show");
  }
```

In this way in development your code will call test.local/ajax/customers.php, while in production it will resolve to yoursite.com/ajax/customers.php

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out by putting a PHP show errors on the ajax page and it was not calling a PDO include correctly.

The lesson is **always** include this on an ajax page until you are happy with it!

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
?>
```

Thanks everyone for your help.